# Issue in Python - AcloudguruDL

Tags: python

thanks for such a great python program. I have done all the steps that are mentioned in https://github.com/r0oth3x49/acloud-dl. still I am getting issues. I am getting below error while executing "python acloud-dl.py -c file_containing_cookie.txt" command after starting course from ACG(Google Chrome), i.e,

"[-] : unable to find file 'file_containing_cookie.txt'."

can you please suggest if any different approach required.

Regards,
Syed Jakeer

Answer (score 0):

open 'file_containing_cookie.txt'
and before the authentication code
write:

```
auth0_token= <puth here your auth code> delete "< >"
```

and run again the command:
python acloud-dl.py -c file_containing_cookie.txt

Comment: Thanks for response, But it's not working. A detailed description will be helpful.